# How to connect keypad to Pi Zero

Tags: gpio, pi-zero-w, analog-to-digital

I've tried to find info but with no luck.
I'm trying to make a project - barcode scanner - using RPI zero. I need a keypad to input quantities when I scan a barcode.
I am unable to find any phone-style keypad dedicated to RPI, so I was advised to use one of the following:

1. https://www.dfrobot.com/product-2267.html
2. https://www.waveshare.com/4x4-keypad.htm
3. https://botland.store/keyboards-for-arduino/4468-keyboard-matrix-4x4-tact-switch-analog-output-waveshare-4431-5904422305628.html

The problem is I cannot find any documentation about how to connect it to the RPI. I mean wiring and a code (best would be in Python)
Any hints? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: i have a difficult time believing that you found nothing when you googled `rpi keypad`

Comment: also you can get barcode scanners that behave like a usb keyboard... so why not just another keyboard? they have usb numpads

Comment: Look for USB number pad.

Answer (score 0):

The question is:

How do you want to connect the keypad to the Raspberry Pi?

You could either go via USB or via GPIO, the latter is more compact for hardware.

Look for the CARDKB-MINI-KEYBOARD by M5Stack, it is very easy to integrate via I2C interface (four wires) and easy to use with Python reading out GPIO.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of these to attach a USB keyboard and mouse
https://thepihut.com/products/ethernet-hub-and-usb-hub-w-micro-usb-otg-connector

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/128548)

Comment: Fair do's, link is to a USB hub with a micro USB connector, adds standard USB sockets and a RJ45 network socket.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).